# Resolve expression references to actual values

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, expression

I want to log the actual values in an expression rather than the references to the properties/fields/constants used in the expression. I have a fiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7SNxAq the code of which (for posterity) is:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var input = new Foo
        {
            Shape = "Sphere",
            SizeType = SizeType.Small
        };

        Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> expression = f =>
            f.Hue == Constants.Hues.Red &&
            f.Shape == input.Shape &&
            f.Size == input.SizeType.ToString() &&
            !f.IsDeleted;

        Console.WriteLine(expression);
    }
}

internal class Foo
{
    public string Hue { get; set; }
    public string Shape { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; }
    public SizeType SizeType { get; set; }
}

internal enum SizeType
{
    Small, Medium, Large
}

internal class Constants
{
    public class Hues
    {
        public static string Red = "#f00";
    }
}
```

The result of `Console.WriteLine(expression)` is:

```
f => ((((f.Hue == Hues.Red) AndAlso (f.Shape == value(Program+<>c__DisplayClass0_0).input.Shape)) AndAlso (f.Size == value(Program+<>c__DisplayClass0_0).input.SizeType.ToString())) AndAlso Not(f.IsDeleted))
```

But I'd like to see something like this

```
f => ((((f.Hue == Hues.Red) AndAlso (f.Shape == "Sphere")) AndAlso (f.Size == "Small")) AndAlso Not(f.IsDeleted))
```

Can this be done, or am I missing the point of expressions?

Comment: You expression is closing over `input`. Why not pass a  second`Foo` in and use it in the expression: `Expression<Func<Foo, Foo, bool>>`

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Sean but this contrived example is closest to the read code which is far too much to share here. It also doesn't "expand" or "resolve" the references to their values.

Answer (score 1):

So what is needed is to get rid of closures. For that, an Expression tree needs to be rewritten (be careful, not all cases are considered in the Expression visitor):

```
public static void Main()
{
    // ...

    var updated = (Expression<Func<Foo, bool>>)
        new ClosureResolver().Visit(expression);

    // Outputs:
    // f => ((((f.Hue == Hues.Red) AndAlso (f.Shape == "Sphere")) AndAlso (f.Size == "Small")) AndAlso Not(f.IsDeleted))
    Console.WriteLine(updated);
}


public class ClosureResolver : ExpressionVisitor
{
    protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
    {
        if (node.Arguments.Count == 0)
        {
            var objExpr = Visit(node.Object);

            if (objExpr is ConstantExpression objConstExpr)
            {
                var res = node.Method.Invoke(objConstExpr.Value, new object[0]);
                return Expression.Constant(res);
            }
        }

        return base.VisitMethodCall(node);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
        var childExpr = Visit(node.Expression);

        if (childExpr is ConstantExpression constExpr)
        {
            if (node.Member is FieldInfo field)
            {
                var constVal = field.GetValue(constExpr.Value);
                return Expression.Constant(constVal);
            }
            else if (node.Member is PropertyInfo prop)
            {
                var constVal = prop.GetValue(constExpr.Value);
                return Expression.Constant(constVal);
            }
        }

        return base.VisitMember(node);
    }
}
```

Once the Expression tree is rewritten - it'll no longer have closures, so it may behave differently in the cases when `input` has been changed:

```
static void ClosureDemo()
{
    var input = new Foo { Shape = "Sphere" };

    Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> expr = f =>
        f.Shape == input.Shape;

    var updated = (Expression<Func<Foo, bool>>) 
        new ClosureResolver().Visit(expr);

    var fn = expr.Compile();
    var updatedFn = updated.Compile();


    Console.WriteLine(fn(input)); // True
    Console.WriteLine(updatedFn(input)); // True

    input.Shape = "Cube";

    Console.WriteLine(fn(input)); // True
    Console.WriteLine(updatedFn(input)); // False
}
```

Comment: Therein lies the rub I think. Covering all cases is a non-trivial undertaking. Even in this simple example we have issues:
`Run-time exception (line -1): Attempt by method 'ClosureResolver.VisitMember(System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression)' to access field 'Program+<>c__DisplayClass0_0.input' failed.`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I was testing against .NET Core 3.1 - the sample works there: https://dotnetfiddle.net/NapHBB

I was also able to run the sample with .NET Framework 4.7 locally, but not in DotNetFiddle - there must be a security configuration issue preventing executing that logic.

Comment: Please find a project I started on GitHub: https://github.com/AndreyChechel/Explosuress

Now the logic handles more cases including method arguments, indexers and static fields/properties. A NuGet package is also available.

Comment: Thank you @AndreyCh for Explosuress!
It's working like a charm.